# Leer JSON usando PHP

Tags: php, json

Como podría acceder a cada uno de los valores de este JSON usando PHP? por ejemplo al valor de "id" del primero CLIENTE, les dejo el JSON`

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "object": "customer",
        "id": "cus_test_eJBVcgFjS1TgWkkt",
        "creation_date": 1571265132000,
        "email": "www@5da79a941b7d8me.com",
        "antifraud_details": {
            "first_name": "Will",
            "last_name": "Muro",
            "address": "av lima 123",
            "address_city": "lima",
            "country_code": "PE",
            "phone": "899898999",
            "object": "client"
        },
        "cards": [],
        "metadata": {
            "test": "test"
        }
    },

],

}
```

Comment: Hola, eso se hace con "json_decode()".

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que cuando uno empieza a usar JSON se encuentra muchas veces perdido ante objetos grandes (lo digo por propia experiencia), aporto esta respuesta con la esperanza de dar una clave importante para aprender a manejar los objetos JSON.

**Tienes que fijarte en todos los casos si el objeto está entre `{ }` o entre `[ ]`**. Esa es la clave, no hay otra. Si entiendes eso, ya puedes leer **cualquier JSON** sin equivocarte.

Me explico:

- Si está entre `{ }` es un objeto JSON y puedes acceder a sus propiedades **directamente** mediante la notación `$objeto->propiedad`.
- Si está entre `[ ]` es un array JSON y puedes acceder a sus objetos/propiedades usando un bucle o indicando el índice, por ejemplo: `$objeto[0]->propiedad`.

Quizá ayude una descripción de tu objeto:

- Es un objeto JSON llamado `data`, porque empieza así:

  ```
  {
      "data":
  ```

  Ya dijimos que lo que empieza con `{` es un objeto. Por tanto el elemento global es un objeto JSON. Si fuera un array empezaría así `[ "data" ... ]`
- En la clave `data` hay un array de objetos. Ya dijimos que todo lo que empieza así `[` es un array de objetos. Y vemos que después de `"data":` tenemos un `[`. El primero objeto que hay en ese array (índice 0) sería este:

  ```
  {
      "object": "customer",
      "id": "cus_test_eJBVcgFjS1TgWkkt",
      "creation_date": 1571265132000,
      "email": "www@5da79a941b7d8me.com",
      "antifraud_details": {
          "first_name": "Will",
          "last_name": "Muro",
          "address": "av lima 123",
          "address_city": "lima",
          "country_code": "PE",
          "phone": "899898999",
          "object": "client"
      },
      "cards": [],
      "metadata": {
          "test": "test"
      }
  },
  ```
- Podemos describir también este objeto. Por lo general, los objetos que hay dentro de un array son todos iguales en la estructura, o sea, tienen las mismas propiedades. Este objeto tiene una propiedad `customer` cuyo valor es una simple cadena. Podría tener propiedades simples del tipo entero (números) o del tipo booleano, pero esto tiene poca importancia aquí. Llama la atención la propiedad `antifraud_details`. No es una cadena, no es un entero, no es un boleeano, ¿qué es? no es Superman, es **un objeto JSON** que está anidado en esa propiedad. Lo mismo ocurre con la propiedad `metadata` que está más abajo. Otra propiedad interesante es `cards`. Es un array que está vacío. En la prueba le pondré valor para indicar la forma de lectura global de este objeto.

Sabiendo todo esto, ya sabes cómo leer el objeto completo. Asumiendo que el mismo está bien definido, que no tiene por ejemplo propiedades dispares y cosas así.

Vamos a leerlo:

En el código PHP quiero señalar que muchos usuarios tienen la costumbre de convertir los objetos JSON a array pasándole `true` a `json_decode`. Esto no es necesario, a no ser que necesites implementar una lectura genérica para imprimir las claves y los valores mediante un `foreach ($array as $k=>$v) { echo "$k: $v\n"; }`. En los otros casos, es mejor tratar el JSON como tal, como un objeto.

```
$mData= '
{
    "data": [{
        "object": "customer",
        "id": "cus_test_eJBVcgFjS1TgWkkt",
        "creation_date": 1571265132000,
        "email": "www@5da79a941b7d8me.com",
        "antifraud_details": {
            "first_name": "Will",
            "last_name": "Muro",
            "address": "av lima 123",
            "address_city": "lima",
            "country_code": "PE",
            "phone": "899898999",
            "object": "client"
        },
        "cards": [1,2,99],
        "metadata": {
            "test": "test"
        }
    }]
}
';
$json=json_decode($mData);
$allData=$json->data;
#Variable que usaremos para concatenar
$html=PHP_EOL;

foreach ($allData as $data) {
    $html.=$data->object.PHP_EOL;
    $html.=$data->id.PHP_EOL;
    $html.=$data->creation_date.PHP_EOL;
    $html.=$data->object.PHP_EOL;
    $html.=$data->email.PHP_EOL;
    #Referencia al objeto anidado
    $antifraud=$data->antifraud_details;
    $html.="Detalles antifraude:".PHP_EOL;
        $html.="\t".$antifraud->first_name.PHP_EOL;
        $html.="\t".$antifraud->last_name.PHP_EOL;
        $html.="\t".$antifraud->address.PHP_EOL;
        $html.="\t".$antifraud->address_city.PHP_EOL;
        $html.="\t".$antifraud->country_code.PHP_EOL;
        $html.="\t".$antifraud->phone.PHP_EOL;
        $html.="\t".$antifraud->object.PHP_EOL;

    #Referencia al array anidado
    $cards=$data->cards;
    #Verificamos que no está vacío
    if ($cards) {
        $html.="Cards:".PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($cards as $card) {
            $html.="\t$card".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    #Referencia al objeto anidado
    $meta=$data->metadata;
    $html.="Metadata:".PHP_EOL;
        $html.="\t".$meta->test.PHP_EOL;
    $html.=PHP_EOL;
}

echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```
customer
cus_test_eJBVcgFjS1TgWkkt
1571265132000
customer
www@5da79a941b7d8me.com
Detalles antifraude:
    Will
    Muro
    av lima 123
    lima
    PE
    899898999
    client
Cards:
    1
    2
    99
Metadata:
    test
```

Aquí se lee el objeto dentro de un `foreach` por ser un array de objetos, pero también puedes obtener el primer elemento así:

```
$firstData=$allData[0];
```

Y leer las propiedades del mismo modo que se hace en el `foreach`. Ejemplo:

```
echo $firstData->object;
```

Comment: en lo unico que no estoy de acuerdo es de no convertir el array json con json_decode(, true). dependiendo de esto, la iteracion por las propiedades pasa a ser -> o a utilizar [""], cosa que en php con los arrays asociativos permite utilizar un bucle con foreach ($lista as $key=> $value). Aparte, si recibes el json de una api, no conoces las propiedades, por lo que se manejaria mejor con un true. (Por supuesto, si es necesario un objeto, no hay mas que hablar) :)

Comment: Tienes toda la razón en eso @Jakala, en cuanto pueda re-escribo ese párrafo. Gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy simple:

```
$decode = json_decode($miArray);
print_r($decode)
```

Por lo general te va a venir como objeto.

Es decir:

data->id

Entonces te deberia quedar

```
$decode->data->id
```

Otra que podes hacer es un foreach o algo por el estilo para no andar poniendo el data siempre.